# ListView - Card (Flutter Layout)

Tags: dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

Flutters!

I need to recreate this layout in Flutter to be displayed as items in a ListView.
Both layouts (Emma & Tonny) are the same.. the only difference is the colors that depend on some other data/status, something that I will decide programmatically later.

[image]

I already have the ListView.builder as follow:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: WeeklyList.contacts.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {    
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onTapMe(WeeklyList.contacts[index]),
      child: TripItemCard(index, WeeklyList.contacts[index]));
})
```

and.... the main missing guy:

```
Widget TripItemCard(int index, Info info) {      
    return SizedBox(
            height: 116,
            child: Card(
        
            //.... Card Layout.....
        
            )
);
```

NOTE: I wrapped the Card with a SizedBox to be able to have a Height specified for all cards.

There are 8 widgets in total:

```
    1- The Card
    2- Picture
    3- Fullname
    4- Role
    5- PickUp Label
    6- PickUp Time
    7- DropOff Label
    8- DropOff Time
```

Lastly and Very Important Things

```
1- Please be advised that there are 2 TEXTs (Name and DropOff Status) who have BACKGROUND and TEXT color... and both of them... fully expanded (width). This is very important to maintain the horizontal color balance.

2- Also PickUp and DropOff are aligned to the right where the PickUp and DropOff Time/Status respectively are aligned to the left.
```

PLEASE.Help();

thanks.dart

Answer (score 0):

The basic layout should look like this and you can add the details to it.

```
Row(children: [
            Image.asset(name),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: const color,
                  child: const Text(data),
                ),
                Text(data),
                Text(data),
                Text(data),
                ],
            ),],),
```